# Increase ZooKeeper negotiated timeout in a MapReduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-zookeeper

Need to increase the negotiated timeout for my MapReduce job.

I tried setting following property:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("zk.connectiontimeout.ms", "60000");
```

But that didn't help.  Still keep getting the message given below.  How do I programatically  change this value?

Here's the message:

15/03/27 11:46:40 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server , sessionid = 0x14bxxbbf2c9e, negotiated timeout = 30000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZooKeeper configurations are only used by the ZooKeeper Servers as they are started. You can't change them after they are already running.

Comment: But... why are you doing this?

Comment: We keep getting this message: "fs.JobTrackerWatcher: Retrying to connect ZooKeeper Attempt# 25" every 30 seconds.  We can't figure out exactly why, but our guess is that ZooKeeper keeps loosing connections with Data/Task/Edge Nodes (could it be?).  Until we figure out the real reason this change will cut down the number of messages.  I guess real question is:  "What causes ZooKeeper to keep Retrying?"

Comment: That sounds like a pretty serious issue with the cluster. I couldn't say here what it is, but I would suggest there's not much point worrying about having too many messages and just to worry about fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set ticktime in zookeeper configuration .
 @ path ZooKeeper/conf  edit the configuration file 
By default ticktime=2000
 You can change the ticktime and restart zookeeper service ..

```
Here are detail configuration parameters :
#The number of milliseconds of each tick  
tickTime=5000
#The number of ticks that the initial 
#synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
#The number of ticks that can pass between 
#sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5
#the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=/tmp/zookeep`
#the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
```